# LAMMPS Error - Incorrect args for pair coefficients

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, lammps

With only one atom type, I used:

```
pair_style eam/fs
pair_coeff * * /potentials/Zr_#2.eam.fs Zr
```

But I keep getting the error: Incorrect args for pair coefficients.  I am also sure that the path to the potential file is correct.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You're potential file is incorrectly named.  LAMMPS will interpret the '#' in:

```
pair_coeff * * /potentials/Zr_#2.eam.fs Zr
```

as the start of a comment.

Rename your potential file and it should work.